# running a for loop in a foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have to write the contents in this format

```
somename1  value1 value2 value1 value2 ....
somename2  value1 value2 value1 value2 ....
somename3  value1 value2 value1 value2 ....
somename4  value1 value2 value1 value2 ....
somename5  value1 value2 value1 value2 ....
```

value1 and value2 are the part of the x and y co-ordinates of a point, so for this I have created a class:

```
class Points
{
 string name;
 double[] X;
 double[] Y;
}

class PointsCollection
{
  List<Points> aPoints
}

//now when accessing the PointCollection
foreach(Points aPoints in PointsCollection)
{
   stream.Write(aPoints.Name)
   //now i have to write the value1 and valud2

}

possible code

//now when accessing the PointCollection
foreach(Points aPoints in PointsCollection)
{
   stream.Write(aPoints.Name)
   int length1 = aPoints.Real;
   int length2 = aPoints.Imag;
   for(int i = 0 ; i < length1; i++)
   {
            stream.Write(aPoints.Real[i]);
            stream.Write(",");
            stream.Write(aPoints.Imag[i]);

    }
     stream.WriteLine();

}
```

Question : Is it the correct to use for loop inside the foreachloop?

Comment: may be move the internal loop to a different method so that it looks neat.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, nesting for loops in foreach (or foreach in for) is correct!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the correct to use for loop inside the foreach loop?

Loops inside loops – "nested loops" – is a normal approach. Languages like C# allow you to freely nest control structures (loops, `if`, ...) inside each other. Without this many problems would be harder to solve.

The only danger is making functions long and hard to understand and maintain: the solution is to break the inner control structures into their own methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, except I'd make sure that `length1` and `length2` are equal before proceeding ;)

You could also do this:

```
foreach(Points aPoints in PointsCollection) 
{
   stream.Write(aPoints.Name)
   foreach (var complexNumber in aPoints.Real.Zip(aPoints.Imag,
       (real, imag) => new { Real = real, Imag = imag }))
   {
        stream.Write(complexNumber.Real);
        stream.Write(",");
        stream.Write(complexNumber.Imag);

   }
   stream.WriteLine();
}
```

But that is just showing off and doesn't really make your code clearer. I think your version was nicer and more to the point...

Oh, and try running the code, because your formatting is off whack and you'll need to tinker it a bit first ;)

Answer (score 0):

I will optimize with a **StringBuilder** and make only one call to stream.Write() for each loop.
Other than that, there is a little error in reading the length of the Real array, but I suppose it is only a typing error here on SO.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//now when accessing the PointCollection 
foreach(Points aPoints in PointsCollection) 
{ 
   sb.Clear();
   sb.Append(aPoints.Name);
   int length1 = aPoints.Real.Lenght;  // Get the length of Real array
   // int length2 = aPoints.Imag; // Not needed???
   for(int i = 0 ; i < length1; i++) 
   { 
        sb.AppendFormat("{0},{1} ", aPoints.Real[i], aPoints.Imag[i]); 
   } 
   sb.AppendLine(); 
   stream.Write(sb.ToString()); 
}
```